# How to fix the error «Access denied - Invalid HELO name»?

Tags: email, ubuntu, smtp, exim

I have exim on server №1 (1.1.1.1). A mailbox `info` was created, and email was sending and receiving successfully. But when I perform sending from server №2 (2.2.2.2), using an email and password for authentication, the mail server does not let me, giving the following error:

> H=mailer.server2.com (1.1.1.1) [2.2.2.2] rejected MAIL : Access denied
>       - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.3)

How can I adjust the resolution to be sent from any server with any HELO №2 (2.2.2.2)?

Ubuntu was installed on all servers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an issues with your mail client setting, Please try to update SMTP authentication setting on your mail client and check this again.